# How to (nicely) template match multiple specific child elements (union) within wider XPATH

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to match a set of particular elements, but only ones which are children of another element structure (let's say it's input or select elements only somewhere inside `div`s with the class "special-sauce" on them). Normally, this would be easy so far as XPATH: we could parenthetically union the targeted children, like so:

```
 div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')//(input | select)
```

But this is where XSLT throws a curve ball, when we try to use this as a template match (at least in Saxon):

```
 <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')//(input | select)">
```

> {"error":"The xsl file (/section-settings.xsl) could not be parsed.
>   Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error
>   detected.","code":"TRANSFORM_ERROR","location":null,"causes":["Fatal
>   Error: Token \"(\" not allowed here in an XSLT pattern"]}

Basically, parentheticals aren't allowed as part of a template match at the main pathing level (they still work fine inside of conditionals/etc, obviously).

So what to do?

Well, technically, using a union can still work, but we would have to repeat the ancestor XPATH each time, since we can't parenthetically enclose the children:

```
 <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')//input 
     | div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')//select">
```

This is doable (not very pretty, but sure, we can handle that! line breaks can work here to help our sanity yay) in our simple example here, but it gets problematic with more complex XPATH, especially if the parenthetical union would have been in the middle of a longer xpath, or for a lot of elements.

e.g.

```
div[contains(@class, 'major-mess')]/div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')]//(dataset | optgroup | fieldset)//(button | option | label)
```

becomes

```
a crazy mess.
```

Ok, that quickly becomes less of an option in more complex examples. And while structuring our XSLT differently might help (intermediary matches, using modality, etc), the question remains:

### How can we *gracefully* template match using unions of individual child elements within a larger XPATH pattern when parentheticals won't work?

An example sheet for the first example:

```
 <div class="special-sauce">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="INHERITED:" />
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="INHERITED: ">INHERIT: </option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="param3vals" value="INHERITED: " />
            INHERIT:
        </label>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="not-special"><input type="text" id="contact-info-include-path" size="90">     
     <label>contact</label>
 </input></div>
 <div class="sad-panda"><input type="text" id="sidenav-include-path" size="90">
     <label>sidenav</label>
 </input></div>
```

Note: this does assume that an identity transform is running as the primary method of handling the input document.

While there are other questions which could validly receive similar answers as, for example, the one I give below, I felt the context of those questions was usually more general (such that a top level union would be fine as their answer without complication), more specific in ways that didn't match, or simply too different. Hence the Q&A format.

### XSLT 1.0 vs 2.0 vs 3.0

Michael Kay [correctly notes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487670/how-to-nicely-template-match-multiple-specific-child-elements-union-within-w#32496158) below that while the original pattern attempted here doesn't work in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, it should work in a (fully) XSLT 3.0 compatible processor. I'm currently on a system using Saxon 9.3, which is technically XSLT 2.0. I just want to call extra attention to that answer for those who are on a 3.0 system.

Answer (score 4):

I looked all over and most answers to similar problems involved copying the repeated portion of the XPATH to each element and unioning it all together. But there is a better way! It's easy to forget that matching a particular element is relatively equivalent to matching that element's name within XPATH.

### Use `name()` or `local-name()` instead of matching on the element directly within the template match pattern*.

Be aware of your namespace issues/needs when picking which to use. This still allows for advanced conditionals on attributes/etc of those elements.

The first match, for example, becomes:

```
 <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')//
     element()[local-name() = ('input', 'select')]">
```

There's not a huge gain here in terms of space or time to write this out, but we *do* reduce redundancy and the associated data consistency errors that can result (all too often, especially if later making changes).

Where this really shines is the last example in the question (the mess):

```
 <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'major-mess')]/
     div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')]//
     element()[local-name() = ('dataset', 'optgroup', 'fieldset')]//
     element()[local-name() = ('button', 'option', 'label')]">
```

---

And since I can't remember if that's fully XSLT/XPATH 1.0 compatible by creating the element tree-fragment parenthetically for comparison, if you do need backwards compatibility the "`contains()` with bracketing separator tokens" (reducing chances of a false positive from another element being a substring of the full name targeted) pattern always works too:

```
 <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'major-mess')]/
     div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')]//
     element()[contains('|dataset|optgroup|fieldset|'), concat('|', local-name(), '|'))]//
     element()[contains('|button|option|label|', concat('|', local-name(), '|'))]">
```

---

### * = "match pattern" vs "XPath"

If you're struggling with understanding why the naive approach (the first thing I attempted in the question) fails in XSLT, it helps to understand that template rules like "match" must follow [XSLT patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns), which are only essentially a sub set of valid XPath expressions (which easily makes things more confusing to distinguish and remember, especially when many sources just pretend it's all XPath entirely). Note that parentheses only show up as a valid option to use as [expression tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-ExprToken) which are only found within expressions within [predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates), not within any other portion of the location path or location steps.

---

Final Considerations

Performance: I have no idea whether there are notable performance differences with this approach versus unioning each seperate element as a full path to each one, or whether there is even a real performance difference between addressing an element natively versus as a predicate on the anonymous `element()` selector. My suspicion is that while most XSLT processors can probably achieve a faster DOM tree search when a single match is written using the native path structure versus a predicate with name() function on the anonymous selector, the union cases may perform faster depending on how well the processor tries to pre-compile and optimize for logic patterns. I will leave that task for someone else to try benchmarking, because ultimately the real hurdle becomes developer sanity and maintenance issues (likelihood of incurring human errors). In complex matches, I feel that any small performance penalty will likely be easily met by the simple legibility and reduced/eliminated data redundancy of this approach.

Comment: I would certainly discourage use of string-matching on the value of name() or local-name() - in Saxon it turns the pattern-matching code from a hash table lookup to a serial search of all possible patterns.

Comment: So the key here becomes reducing the search scope via the surrounding pattern as much as possible, I assume?

Comment: You might find John Lumley's XML London 2015 paper on XSLT pattern matching interesting. http://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmllondon-2015jl.pdf

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you, it looks like it will be some interesting reading! Most of the time I don't have to be *as* concerned w/ performance as in a live dynamic processing system, since ours publishes static html pages from the xslt processing and embeds php/asp/cf (depends on target env) as needed to handle any dynamic aspects, but bulk re-publishing entire sites at once (thousands of pages or more) starts to see performance become more of a concern. Most matches like this are occurring against our html templates rather than page content itself, so the scope stays somewhat smaller hopefully.

Comment: Why not use the completely trick-less and well performing pure XPath 1.0 expression of this general type: `HeadPathExpression/*[self::name1 or self::name2 or self::name3]` ?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev partly because... in all honesty... I sometimes forget about the from-self axis? You're TOTALLY correct that it would work perfectly fine for a simple case like what I posed here, with pre-defined/immutable QNames. Which is culpa mea in trying to simplify the question for what I'm doing that lead to my using this particular solution. Where it breaks is when you're dealing with passed values either from a sheet (xpath to attribute on an element, interior text/etc) or as params/variables. Do you mind if I include this in this answer along with the differences in flexibility?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your pattern is legal in XSLT 3.0 as written. But I guess you want an XSLT 2.0 solution...

One great way that people often overlook is to use schema-aware patterns. If you want to match a choice of elements, it's quite likely that they are closely related in the schema, for example by having a common type T or by being members of a substitution group S. You can then write

```
div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')//schema-element(S)
```

or

```
div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')//element(*, T)
```

But I guess you want a solution that isn't schema-aware...

In that case, I don't think I can offer anything better than what you've got.

Sometimes multiple modes are the answer: for example something like

```
<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')]">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="special"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="select|input" mode="special">
```

Generally I think modes are greatly under-used.

Comment: Strangely, the original pattern isn't working in the CMS we're running this on… and xsl:version reports 2.0 with xsl:vendor reporting it's only Saxon 9.3.0.5, so I guess that would be why. Which is strange since some XSLT 3.0 functions like xsl:evaluate are working as such, rather than as saxon specific or fn: calls, so I'd assumed (yes yes I know) we were on a version supporting 3.0. Which of course is mentioned in the saxon documentation now that I'm looking again. 

Totally correct that XSLT 3.0 should work: ParenthesizedExprP is allowed as top level syntax per http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30

Comment: What I meant to say, though, is I REALLY like the idea of using schema aware patterns. It wouldn't work for all cases, but it would be fantastic where it does work.

While I do like and use modes quite a bit, they come with their own considerations, especially when identity transforming an entire document (such as xhtml sheets) instead of pulling out minimal parts of it. For immediate children where order didn't matter that would be fine (match one mode, empty match on default to still apply on that), but for unknown depth with other matching on default and order issues it becomes problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Why not split this template into two or three (one for each level) with modes? Something like

```
<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'special-sauce')">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//select|input" mode="special-sauce"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="select|input" mode="special-sauce">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

In my opinion this way it reads clearer.

Comment: As I alluded to in the question, it can definitely work for particular cases! I prefer to avoid it, where possible, though, because you're now going to be juggling an exclusion on the default mode (or dealing with multiple copies being inserted), you have to add in the appropriate identity transform (copy, etc) on the div you matched if you do want to insert it into the result tree and/or continue other matching on any other children of it, and you're now dealing with inter-dependencies in separate matches. Most importantly, you can run into SEVERE issues of placement in the result tree.